# Flutter web: Values retrieved from Firestore map are truncated when added to List

Tags: dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

In my Flutter Web application I am retrieving values from the map `timeslots` in Firestore.
This is what the data looks like:

[image]

But, instead of retrieving the whole list of values, I get a truncated list like this:

```
[Mo-Washing-(09:00-10:00, 10:00-11:00, 11:00-12:00, ..., 20:00-21:00, 21:00-22:00)]
```

Below I have included the 2 functions responsible for retrieving the data and adding it to the list `object`

```
static List object = [];
static Map<String, dynamic> timeDetails = {};
static Map<String, dynamic> userDetails = {};

  checkExists(docuID) async {
    return await firestore()
        .collection('environments')
        .doc(docuID)
        .get()
        .then((val) {
      userDetails.addAll(val.data());
    }).whenComplete(() async {
        fs.DocumentSnapshot snapShot = await firestore()
            .collection('environments')
            .doc(docuID)
            .collection('Washing')
            .doc('monday')
            .get();
        if (snapShot == null || !snapShot.exists) {
          print('does not exist');
        } else {
          await getData(docuID, 'Washing');
        }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

   getData(docuID, machineName) async {
    return await firestore()
        .collection('environments')
        .doc(docuID)
        .collection(machineName)
        .doc('monday')
        .get()
        .then((val) {
      timeDetails.addAll(val.data());
    }).whenComplete(() {
      object.add('Mo-$machineName-${timeDetails['timeslots'].values}');
      print(object);
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

This also happens in `debugPrint`. Would anyone know why this is happening and how I could solve it? Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: can you print the length of the list to verify if the list is actually truncated or its just the print output that is truncated?

Comment: When I `print(timeDetails['timeslots'].values.length)` the output is 13, and that would be the whole list

Comment: Both `print` and `debugPrint` truncate the output if it's too long. You can find some workaround [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665)

Comment: I tried the workaround and debugPrint but none of that worked, I just added an answer that did the trick for me, but thank you for your help! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither the [workaround](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22665) as mentioned on Github nor `debugPrint` worked for me, but I managed to solve this by adding `.toList()` to my getData function:

```
   getData(docuID, machineName) async {
    return await firestore()
        .collection('environments')
        .doc(docuID)
        .collection(machineName)
        .doc('monday')
        .get()
        .then((val) {
      timeDetails.addAll(val.data());
    }).whenComplete(() {
      //toList() is added here to .add
      object.add('Mo-$machineName-${timeDetails['timeslots'].values.toList()}');
      print(object);
      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

Output:

```
[Mo-Washing-[09:00-10:00, 10:00-11:00, 11:00-12:00, 12:00-13:00, 13:00-14:00, 14:00-15:00, 15:00-16:00, 16:00-17:00, 17:00-18:00, 18:00-19:00, 19:00-20:00, 20:00-21:00, 21:00-22:00]
```